# Shopify - how to change body background color (over scroll on mobile)

Tags: css, shopify, background-color, shopify-template

[image]
I do have a weird background color on mobile when I am over scrolling (I am not sure how it's called, but I suppose is the body one)

Can you please help me in order to change the color into white.

Comment: Which one, on the header or footer of the image?

Comment: above the header, the green/blue color

Comment: You need to share the URL to check it, is it comes from the website end or the default browser behavior

Answer (score 0):

This comes from an accent tag in the head of the website.

Add this near the top of theme.liquid. Of course, replace the colour with your own.

```html
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ecd96f">
```